# SP2010 QuickLaunch Hidden by css rules between head tags - I don't want this

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010

Qucklaunch navigation is hidden on a publishing site I'm working with. There is some CSS being sent in the header of the HTML document, not in a linked CSS.

```
.v4master #s4-leftpanel { display: none; } 
.v4master .s4-ca { margin-left: 0px; }
```

I do not see these css rules when i look at the master page.

CSS linked that the custom master page is not doing this. If I switch back to the untouched v4.master, the result is the same.

"enable quick launch" is checked under Site Actions > Site Settings > Tree View.

Where are these css rules getting inserted into the document and how do I prevent it???

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a result of using a page layout that doesn't allow the quicklaunch.  As soon as i changed to a page layout that displays the left navigation, it showed up.